# Damn Small Linux does not detect hard drive but Debian can see it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, damn-small-linux

I have a Toshiba Dynabook 2010 laptop and I want to install Damn Small Linux (DSL) on it. The problem is when I boot with DSL there is no hard drive named `/dev/hda1` and `fdisk -l` command does not return.

I could only boot into DSL if I use the `nofstab` as a kernel parameter. When I boot with `fstab` then a kernel panic appears.

I again checked, now there is a /dev/hda but my hda should contain two ext3 partitions.
But the problem is the kernel doesn't recognize them. I got Debian in my hard disk too.
The problem is Debian can recognize these two partitions.

How I can get around this?

Comment: What particular version does your DSL kernel have? Modern kernels switched to libata and all hdd devices, even IDE ones are named sd*, just like the newer SATA ones.

Comment: fdisk needs super user privileges, try `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 1):

Damn Small Linux is no longer being updated.  I suggest trying something more current, like Puppy Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://damnsmalllinux.org/forums/index.php?topic=5.0

In case anyone else has a similar difficulty, my netbook is an Asus 1011PX. Under the ‘IDE configuration’ heading (in the BIOS) there are 2 particular sub-headings ie.
1)‘ATA/IDE CONFIGURATION’ with the following options:
-disabled
-compatible
-enhanced.
2) ‘CONFIGURE SATA’ with options
-IDE or
-AHCI.

The manufacturer had set these to ‘enhanced’ and ‘AHCI’ and this did not allow the hard drive to be recognised when trying to install DSL to the hard drive from a USB-based iso.

I therefore first changed the CONFIGURE SATA option to IDE (instead of AHCI) and then changed the ATA/IDE CONFIGURATION to ‘compatible’ (instead of ‘enhanced’) and this allowed a hard drive install with all of the other partitions on the hard drive being accessible within the new hd install.